# When do you use a brushless motor driver and when do you use an ESC?

Tags: driver, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I'm trying to build a drone from scratch on my ARM microntroller on a Tiva C series development board. I know you need a motor driver(controller) to control a motor, but in the case of a brushless motor I'm seeing a brushless motor driver and an ESC (used in RC quadcopters). What's the difference and what should I choose (how difficult is it to interface with)? My goal is to make a PCB with all the components I need in the future to implement on my drone.

Here is the brushless motor driver I have been looking at:

http://www.robotshop.com/en/veyron-5a-brushless-motor-controller.html

Here is the ESC:

http://www.robotshop.com/en/lynxmotion-12a-multirotor-esc-1a-bec-with-connectors.html

Comment: As the linked device is an ESC for brushless motors, it should work. A motor driver should be able to reverse, an ESC doesn't have to. (Reversing is not generally a problem encountered in drones)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Brian, I do want to actually play around with different propeller configurations, so I may need to reverse rotations (reverse thrust in a pusher configuration). So from what you're saying only an driver can do that? Do I need more additional circuitry to use it?